# How can I extract relation between words in a sentence using AI/ML/NLP

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, artificial-intelligence

lets have an example:

1. I am watching breaking bad
2. He is watching Walking Dead
3. Deadpool is being watched by me

In all 3 sentences I want to extract what is being watched (breaking bad, walking dead, deadpool) respectively. What approach should I use to achieve that?

Comment: Do you have training data?

Comment: yes but very less like around 100 sentences like these.

Answer (score 2):

The NLP technique you should start with is called "dependency parsing". There is plenty of tutorials available on the topic. Spacy is one such python library that can do dependency parsing for you. here's a demo of dependency parsing using Spacy - [Displacy Demo](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy)

Another approach to consider is "relation extraction" and specifically extracting SVO (subject, verb, object) relationships from sentences.

Answer (score 2):

This is called "Named Entity Recognition".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition
There are libraries such as spacy, nltk (both python) a lot of companies and services (pretty much every chatbot platform needs this capability including dialogflow, ibm watson, etc.) and lots of implementations using neural networks etc. out there.

There are 3 basic approaches:

State of the Art:

1. Use a big dataset with labeled data where the text is labeled and train a classification algorithm/Neural Network such as BILSTM or BERT for this task. This might also recognize unknown movie titles because of their position in the sentence and the other words of the sentence.
2. Train an unsupervised or supervised representation of all words/entities (LDA, word embeddings, ...), identify the cluster for movies (maby different types of movies are in different clusters...) and label the parts of the input sentence using knn or similar methods.

Old School:

3. Use a Dataset of known movie titles and see if the movie title is a substring of the sentence (String similarity algorithms such as Jaro-Winkler or Levenshtein can be used to make the classification able to handle minor differences and typos). This approach will only recognize known movie titles (the title of nearly every movie is available on IMDB).